# C++ Faster String Parsing?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I am trying to write a parser to parse this dataset: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/mslr/

I wrote the code (below).. However it is too slow.. it takes almost a full minute to parse a few hundred megabytes of data.

I ran a profiler and it said most of the time was spent on boost::split (30%) and boost::lexical_cast (40%) ... any suggestions on how to speed up the code?

Thanks.

```
  std::ifstream train("letor/Fold1/train.txt", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);

  m_train.clear();

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10000 && train.good(); i++) {
    std::size_t query;
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> features;
    double label;

    features.resize(get_feature_size(), false);

    // 2 qid:1 1:3 2:3 3:0 4:0 5:3 6:1 7:1 8:0 9:0 10:1 11:156 12:4 13:0 14:7 15:167 16:6.931275 17:22.076928 18:19.673353 19:22.255383 20:6.926551 21:3 22:3 23:0 24:0 25:6 26:1 27:1 28:0 29:0 30:2 31:1 32:1 33:0 34:0 35:2 36:1 37:1 38:0 39:0 40:2 41:0 42:0 43:0 44:0 45:0 46:0.019231 47:0.75000 48:0 49:0 50:0.035928 51:0.00641 52:0.25000 53:0 54:0 55:0.011976 56:0.00641 57:0.25000 58:0 59:0 60:0.011976 61:0.00641 62:0.25000 63:0 64:0 65:0.011976 66:0 67:0 68:0 69:0 70:0 71:6.931275 72:22.076928 73:0 74:0 75:13.853103 76:1.152128 77:5.99246 78:0 79:0 80:2.297197 81:3.078917 82:8.517343 83:0 84:0 85:6.156595 86:2.310425 87:7.358976 88:0 89:0 90:4.617701 91:0.694726 92:1.084169 93:0 94:0 95:2.78795 96:1 97:1 98:0 99:0 100:1 101:1 102:1 103:0 104:0 105:1 106:12.941469 107:20.59276 108:0 109:0 110:16.766961 111:-18.567793 112:-7.760072 113:-20.838749 114:-25.436074 115:-14.518523 116:-21.710022 117:-21.339609 118:-24.497864 119:-27.690319 120:-20.203779 121:-15.449379 122:-4.474452 123:-23.634899 124:-28.119826 125:-13.581932 126:3 127:62 128:11089534 129:2 130:116 131:64034 132:13 133:3 134:0 135:0 136:0
    std::string line;
    getline(train, line);

    boost::algorithm::trim(line);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    boost::split(tokens, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));

    assert(tokens.size() == 138);

    label = boost::lexical_cast<double>(tokens[0]);
    query = boost::lexical_cast<std::size_t>(tokens[1].substr(tokens[1].find(":") + 1, tokens[1].size()));

    for (std::size_t i = 2; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
      features[i - 2] = boost::lexical_cast<double>(tokens[i].substr(tokens[i].find(":") + 1, tokens[i].size()));
    }

    m_train.push_back(query, features, label);

    train.peek();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, something does not add up. You are running the loop for up to 10K iterations. On every iteration, you are parsing a line of ~1K characters. That's 10MB, not "few hundred MB".

Comment: A typical issue is generally too much memory copying. You are allocating strings, from which you allocate substrings, copying their content into stringstream, ... There is a proposal, to be examined at Kona, for `string_ref` and `array_ref` types, but in the mean time you may have to just be very careful about what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your format correctly, each line starts with a number followed by colon separated pairs. The first pair on each line has a special meaning and consists of an `std::string` and a `size_t` while all other pairs consist of an index (which is ignored) and a `double`. There is no reason to use Boost for this at all: use IOStreams directly:

```
std::streamsize    max(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
std::string        line;
std::istringstream in;
for (std::size_t i(0); i < 1000 && std::getline(train, line); ++i) {
    double label;
    size_t query;
    in.clear();
    in.str(line)
    if ((in >> label).ignore(max, ':') >> query) {
         boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> features;
         while (in.ignore(max, ':') >> feature) {
              features.push_back(feature);
         }
         assert(features.size() == 136);
         m_train.push_back(query, features, label);
    }
}
```

Note that this code is careful to check that reads are actually successful. Your code checked ahead of time if the read would be successful but this doesn't work reliably. For example, if your last line consisted just of a spurious space your `assert()` would trigger which is hardly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Chopping the string multiple times requires memory allocations and deallocations. You could go with the good old `strtod` and char pointers to avoid splitting the string. That will take some care of the 30% spend in string tokenization. As for the 40% in converting sting to doubles, this probably cannot be significantly improved.

If you want to go for a quick, dirty, and amazingly ugly but probably the fastest C-only solution, try this. That test completed in about 35 seconds on a E8300 2.83 GHz CPU. Assuming that all strings have exactly same format.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main ()
{
    const char* test_str = "2 qid:1 1:3 2:3 3:0 4:0 5:3 6:1 7:1 8:0 9:0 10:1 11:156 12:4 13:0 14:7 15:167 16:6.931275 17:22.076928 18:19.673353 19:22.255383 20:6.926551 21:3 22:3 23:0 24:0 25:6 26:1 27:1 28:0 29:0 30:2 31:1 32:1 33:0 34:0 35:2 36:1 37:1 38:0 39:0 40:2 41:0 42:0 43:0 44:0 45:0 46:0.019231 47:0.75000 48:0 49:0 50:0.035928 51:0.00641 52:0.25000 53:0 54:0 55:0.011976 56:0.00641 57:0.25000 58:0 59:0 60:0.011976 61:0.00641 62:0.25000 63:0 64:0 65:0.011976 66:0 67:0 68:0 69:0 70:0 71:6.931275 72:22.076928 73:0 74:0 75:13.853103 76:1.152128 77:5.99246 78:0 79:0 80:2.297197 81:3.078917 82:8.517343 83:0 84:0 85:6.156595 86:2.310425 87:7.358976 88:0 89:0 90:4.617701 91:0.694726 92:1.084169 93:0 94:0 95:2.78795 96:1 97:1 98:0 99:0 100:1 101:1 102:1 103:0 104:0 105:1 106:12.941469 107:20.59276 108:0 109:0 110:16.766961 111:-18.567793 112:-7.760072 113:-20.838749 114:-25.436074 115:-14.518523 116:-21.710022 117:-21.339609 118:-24.497864 119:-27.690319 120:-20.203779 121:-15.449379 122:-4.474452 123:-23.634899 124:-28.119826 125:-13.581932 126:3 127:62 128:11089534 129:2 130:116 131:64034 132:13 133:3 134:0 135:0 136:0";

    const char* format = "%lf qid:%lf 1:%lf 2:%lf 3:%lf 4:%lf 5:%lf 6:%lf 7:%lf 8:%lf 9:%lf 10:%lf 11:%lf 12:%lf 13:%lf 14:%lf 15:%lf 16:%lf 17:%lf 18:%lf 19:%lf 20:%lf 21:%lf 22:%lf 23:%lf 24:%lf 25:%lf 26:%lf 27:%lf 28:%lf 29:%lf 30:%lf 31:%lf 32:%lf 33:%lf 34:%lf 35:%lf 36:%lf 37:%lf 38:%lf 39:%lf 40:%lf 41:%lf 42:%lf 43:%lf 44:%lf 45:%lf 46:%lf 47:%lf 48:%lf 49:%lf 50:%lf 51:%lf 52:%lf 53:%lf 54:%lf 55:%lf 56:%lf 57:%lf 58:%lf 59:%lf 60:%lf 61:%lf 62:%lf 63:%lf 64:%lf 65:%lf 66:%lf 67:%lf 68:%lf 69:%lf 70:%lf 71:%lf 72:%lf 73:%lf 74:%lf 75:%lf 76:%lf 77:%lf 78:%lf 79:%lf 80:%lf 81:%lf 82:%lf 83:%lf 84:%lf 85:%lf 86:%lf 87:%lf 88:%lf 89:%lf 90:%lf 91:%lf 92:%lf 93:%lf 94:%lf 95:%lf 96:%lf 97:%lf 98:%lf 99:%lf 100:%lf 101:%lf 102:%lf 103:%lf 104:%lf 105:%lf 106:%lf 107:%lf 108:%lf 109:%lf 110:%lf 111:%lf 112:%lf 113:%lf 114:%lf 115:%lf 116:%lf 117:%lf 118:%lf 119:%lf 120:%lf 121:%lf 122:%lf 123:%lf 124:%lf 125:%lf 126:%lf 127:%lf 128:%lf 129:%lf 130:%lf 131:%lf 132:%lf 133:%lf 134:%lf 135:%lf 136:%lf";

    double data[138];

    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        sscanf(test_str, format, 
            data+0, data+1, data+2, data+3, data+4, data+5, 
            data+6, data+7, data+8, data+9, data+10, data+11, 
            data+12, data+13, data+14, data+15, data+16, data+17, 
            data+18, data+19, data+20, data+21, data+22, data+23, 
            data+24, data+25, data+26, data+27, data+28, data+29, 
            data+30, data+31, data+32, data+33, data+34, data+35, 
            data+36, data+37, data+38, data+39, data+40, data+41, 
            data+42, data+43, data+44, data+45, data+46, data+47, 
            data+48, data+49, data+50, data+51, data+52, data+53, 
            data+54, data+55, data+56, data+57, data+58, data+59, 
            data+60, data+61, data+62, data+63, data+64, data+65, 
            data+66, data+67, data+68, data+69, data+70, data+71, 
            data+72, data+73, data+74, data+75, data+76, data+77, 
            data+78, data+79, data+80, data+81, data+82, data+83, 
            data+84, data+85, data+86, data+87, data+88, data+89, 
            data+90, data+91, data+92, data+93, data+94, data+95, 
            data+96, data+97, data+98, data+99, data+100, data+101, 
            data+102, data+103, data+104, data+105, data+106, data+107, 
            data+108, data+109, data+110, data+111, data+112, data+113, 
            data+114, data+115, data+116, data+117, data+118, data+119, 
            data+120, data+121, data+122, data+123, data+124, data+125, 
            data+126, data+127, data+128, data+129, data+130, data+131, 
            data+132, data+133, data+134, data+135, data+136, data+137);
    }
}
```

C99 has `vsscanf` that would make it look better. The format string can then be pre-generated dynamically once before the loop, depending on the dataset format. Make sure to check the return value of sscanf to be exactly 138 in this sample.

EDIT: Dietmar Kühl's solution looks clean, and must not be significantly if at all slower than a single sscanf. Best use the code above only as a benchmark reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without some experimentation, but...

I'd start by dropping `boost::split`.  It's making a 
`std::vector<std::string>`, which in turn involves a lot of dynamic
allocation and copying.  What you probably want to do is write some sort
of iterator over a string in which `++` advances to the next token, and
`*` returns a pair of iterators defining the current token.  This avoids
the intermediate data structure.

You can then define a `<<` operator on this pair, something like:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, TextRange const& token )
{
    std::copy( token.begin(), token.end(),
               std::ostream_iterator<char>( dest ) );
    return dest;
}
```

Reducing the time used by `boost::lexical_cast` will be more difficult.
Basically, `boost::lexical_cast` is using `<<` to insert the source into
a `std::stringstream`, and `>>` to extract it.  You can write something
similar, but using your own streambuf, based on the pair of iterators
(very simple), so given the pair of iterators, 1) you don't have to use
`<<` at all, since the pair of iterators becomes the istream, and 2) you
completely avoid creating any intermediate `std::string`.  (You do
**not** want to reimplement the conversion routines in `std::istream`.)